# Invoke not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to delay my scene loading just a bit to let my button sound play through before the new scene gets loaded, but I seem to be having errors, which is weird considering the exact same code worked for my other button. The Debug below does not get called. Thank you!

```
public class DeathScene : MonoBehaviour {
    public void PlayAgain()
    {
        Invoke("Restart", 0.25f);
    }
    void Restart()
    {
        Debug.Log("restart");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `PlayAgain()` is getting called?

Comment: Yes! Debugged it and it is being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Checking `Time.scale` is not zero.
2. Checking `gameObject` is not destoryed.
3. Checking return value of  `IsInvoking` is true.

If all no problem but `Invoke` still not work,it maybe bug of `Invoke`,use `StartCoroutine`.

Comment: Ah! My Time.scale is zero :D. I'll give coroutine a shot! Thank you

Comment: @BrendonSon if your time scale is zero. Pleas use yield return new  WaitForSecondsRealtime.If this help you please accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke` doesn't work for a destroyed `GameObject`. I suppose your `GameObject` gets destroyed before `PlayAgain` is fired. Check it via `OnDestroy`

```
void OnDestroy () {
    Debug.Log("Oops");
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain the Invoke is not on a destroyed GameObject. The code above is for a button.

Comment: While you're certain, try to add OnDestroy like he said to see if that's the issue

Comment: The GameObject is not destroyed

Comment: @BrendonSon ok then can you provide more info and source code? What happens before PlayAgain is called?